# Marketing Cloud Rest API and Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, triggered-send

We have our main BU (business unit) at the top of the tree, and one of the other BUs is TEST. In TEST we have created an `Installed Package` and in that installed package we have added a Server-to-Server API Integration. In the Access tab of that API Integration we've disabled the integration for the Parent BU, and have enabled it for the TEST BU.

When we make Rest API calls to the endpoint created in that API Integration we always get data from the "Main" BU, and not from the TEST BU.

If I create a contact that is available in both the Parent and TEST BU, but if I try to trigger an email based on a `Triggered Send` definition only the definitions created in the Parent BU are available and not the definitions from the TEST BU.

How can I access the data in the TEST BU from the Rest API? And why aren't the permissions preventing me from taking actions on the Parent BU?

Comment: Are you getting your OAuth token using the id/secret of the installed package?

Comment: are you adding in the `account_id` into your Access Token Request? I believe it is required to access any other than the parent BU. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm)

Comment: @Gortonington that was exactly the issue. I was looking at this doc which doesn't show that option https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm

Want to put your comment as the answer so I can give you full credit

Comment: As a note, that documentation you provided is for the 'legacy' process. Which utilizing the `v1/requestToken` endpoint, not the new 'v2' authentications

Comment: Any idea why that clientId/secret is able to get access to the Parent BU?

Comment: I honestly am not sure, there is much still undocumented and 'incomplete' about this new authentication. E.g. it currently will not work with SOAP calls - you need to use legacy authentication or user/pass. This is a known issue to them and they are working on a fix for it. Perhaps your issue is another temporary issue due to a less then seamless release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue is stemming from the `account_id` option in your [request for the access token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm). I believe it is required to access any other than the parent BU.

[image: JSON Parameters for Request Access Token]

Comment: As a note too, apparently if you only have 1 BU, if you do not put the MID in, it wont authenticate your calls

Comment: This worked for me, but it's a bummer because I'd prefer to pass the MID in the body of the call instead of during authentication.

Comment: What I do is create multiple Auth keys up front for each BU I am going to use and then assign those tokens accordingly for each call.  This way you do not need to do multiple calls back and forth during the process.

Comment: Yeah I am actually allowing user to pull from all BU, but then using a filter. It works fine, I just reauthenticate for that BU only when they make the request, but it's a bit slower I'd hoped. Thanks for posting the answer in any case, it definitely works.