# Marketing Cloud - accessing REST API in a child business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, accesstoken, installedpackage

I'm attempting to access a Child Business Unit using an Installed Package created in the Parent Business Unit.

I am `POST`ing this payload

```
{
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  client_id: {{ Parent Business Unit client_id }},
  client_secret: {{ Parent Business Unit client_secret }},
  account_id: {{ Child Business Unit MID }}
}
```

to `https://<yourSubdomain>.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token`

The error message I'm getting back from the API is

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Client authentication failed. Make sure that the client ID and client secret are valid and that the package is installed and enabled.",
  "error_uri": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs"
}
```

I know that the credentials are working because I can successfully get an access token for the Parent BU.

I reviewed the post here [Marketing Cloud Rest API and Business Units](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253417/marketing-cloud-rest-api-and-business-units) and the accepted answer doesn't solve the issue.

Is there something I'm missing in the docs about how to access the Child BU?

Comment: No, I followed the documentation you suggested and the API isn't behaving as I expect it to.  I'm passing the Child BU MID in the `account_id` field and the call is failing.  If I leave it blank or put in the Parent BU MID the call is successful

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging around in the Installed Package screen I looked at the `Access` tab and saw that each of the Child Business Units weren't `Enabled`.

Solution: I had to individually enable each Child Business unit that I wanted to access